# How to show a pic as splash screen during timeperiod of database connectivity

Tags: java, database

I'm trying to add a splash screen in my netbeans desktop application.

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok thankx for this useful tutorial but I found an error this code does't load my image as splash where should I put my splash screen

Comment: @Akanksha Dixit we can only help if you post the methods you tried in an intelligible way :)

Comment: Main problem ia that I can't specify path to pic I tried putting it into resource folder but that didn't work for me. My method to create image is- protected static ImageIcon createimage(String path){java.net.URL imgurl=mypackage.myclass("image/mypic.png")if(imgurl!=null){return ImageIcon imgurl);else{return null;}} I use this but have can't get imge/mypic.jpg . Can you please help me step by step the how and where to add nd us that pic as a icon or something . If u r reading this thanjx for giving ur time thank uhh

Comment: @AkankshaDixit try complementing your question with that piece of code.